# Syntax for adding a timestamp column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, ddl

After research on here I wanted to use "timestamp with time zone" but cannot figure out the proper syntax based on the postgres docs.

```
ALTER TABLE microwaves ADD COLUMN scanned_in DATA_TYPE timestamp with time zone;

ALTER TABLE microwaves ADD COLUMN scanned_in TYPE timestamp with time zone;
```

Both throw errors.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just had the syntax wrong. You don't need the `[DATA] TYPE` part here (that's only needed when you want to change the type) :

```
CREATE TABLE barf
        ( id serial PRIMARY KEY);

ALTER TABLE barf ADD COLUMN scanned_in timestamp with time zone;
```

BTW (just a hint): most of the `ALTER` syntax just mimics the syntax for `CREATE TABLE (...)`: the sub-syntax is mostly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the simple solution as below:

```
ALTER TABLE microwaves ADD COLUMN scanned_in timestamp with time zone;
```

For more details check [PostgreSQL - ADD COLUMN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#id-1.9.3.35.8)